# QuantumEspresso phonon calculations stops abruptly with no error

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, phonons

I was trying to calculate phonon dispersion relations of a monolayer MoS2. I've run an Scf calculations with this input file:

```
&CONTROL
calculation = 'scf'
prefix = 'MoS2_1Layer_ph'
pseudo_dir = '/home/Giuseppe'
outdir = './'
tstress = .true.
tprnfor = .true.
forc_conv_thr = 1.0d-3
nstep = 200
/
&SYSTEM
ibrav = 4
a = 3.135265913000000000
c = 43.12822024985000000
nat = 3
ntyp = 2
ecutwfc = 90
ecutrho = 680
/

&ELECTRONS
mixing_beta = 0.7
conv_thr = 1.0 d-10
diagonalization = 'david'
electron_maxstep =200
/

&IONS
trust_radius_max = 0.2
/
&CELL
cell_dynamics = "bfgs"
cell_dofree = '2Dxy'
/

ATOMIC_SPECIES
Mo 95.9400 Mo.pbesol-spn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
S 32.0660 S.pbesol-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS {angstrom}
Mo 0.0103653871  1.7192376473 21.56417128
 S 1.5780476184  0.9051700832 20.00478826
 S 1.5780476184  0.9051700832 23.12352924

K_POINTS {automatic}
4 4 1 0 0 0
```

and then  I've run with ph.x this file:

```
&inputph
outdir = './'
prefix = 'MoS2_1Layer_ph'
fildvscf = 'dvscf'
ldisp = .true.
fildyn = 'MoS2_1Layer_ph.in'
alpha_mix(1) = 0.3
nq1 = 4,
nq2 = 4,
nq3 = 1,
tr2_ph = 1.0d-12
/
```

And my calculations stops saying "Electric Field Calculations" for hours and I do not know what's happening. Before that in the .out file of the ph file it says "There are 9 irreducible representations" and it continues with :

```
Representation 1 1 modes - To be done
```

and goes on to representation 9. Is it right?